# Display selected columns vertically

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have a table named `orders`.

I want to display `Order Date`, `Sum` of the product quantity ordered and the `product_name`.

Here is the data I want to display:

[Data to Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc2Om.png)

As above, I want product names to be displayed horizontally, with the sum of the product orders displayed vertically by date.

I am using C# and an MS Access database.

I am able to display the data in gridview row-wise. Here is the code:

```
 private void btn_all_orders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       connection.open
       OleDbCommand command = new OleDbcommand();
       command.connection = connection;
       string query = "select order_date as 'Order Date', product_name as       
       'Items', Sum(order_quantity) as 'No of Orders' from order where cust_id = 
       '" + txt_cust_id.Text + "' group by order_date, product_name";
       command.commandText = query;
       OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       da.Fill(dt);
       datagridview.DataSource = dt;
       connectionn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
      Messagebox.Show("Error " + ex);
      connection.Close();
    }
}
```

How do I change this to achieve the goal described above?

Comment: Edit your question and format the code correctly. It seems like you are using a code block for each line, instead try to use a single code block for the whole piece of code.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow ;p so couldn't format correctly. Can not see the option to edit also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for is this:

[image]

What you will need to do is ADD a Column to your to your datatable.
[Then add an expression to that column it.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  da.Fill(dt);
   dt.Columns.Add("TOTAL");
  dt.Columns("Total").Expression = "Count(Product1) + Count(Product2) + Count(Product3)";

   datagridview.DataSource = dt;
   connectionn.Close();
```

The totals on the bottom are coming from your SelectQuery => Sum(order_quantity). You can modify the query to get rid of that.

Some info
[Of course the query could be changed so that it returns a computed column back and then you do not need to do it in the datatable.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sum-data-by-using-a-query-430a669b-e7fd-4c4b-b154-8c8dbbe41c8a)

[Actual SQL for changing the query so that it returns a computed column back - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932205/to-calculate-sum-two-alias-named-columns-in-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932205/to-calculate-sum-two-alias-named-columns-in-sql)

The code above is pseudo - untested code - so please read the links.

**EDIT**
You could also look here : [Display Data Vertically in the DataGridview](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19313/Displaying-Vertical-Rows-in-DataGrid-View)
Too much code to post but basically the real work is done by flipping the dataset - as Mr. Gamal did.

```
public DataSet FlipDataSet(DataSet my_DataSet)
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 foreach (DataTable dt in my_DataSet.Tables)
 {
   DataTable table = new DataTable();

   for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {   table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));  }

   DataRow r;
   for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
   { 
     r = table.NewRow();
     r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
     for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
     {  r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k]; }
     table.Rows.Add(r);
   }
   ds.Tables.Add(table);
 }

 return ds;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my concern is not to display total but display records of product_name vertically. e.g. product_names have like Coat, Napkin then i want Coat and Napkin to be displayed vertically and than display the sum of their quantity ordered date wise.

Comment: @Deepak Vaishnav  In other words you want your Rows as Columns? Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368396/show-datasource-rows-as-columns-on-a-datagridview-winforms
I also edited the answer to provide a code link and the important aspect of the code you will need - please see the EDIT.